# NestJS: How to set global log level for different environments

Tags: logging, nestjs

I am using the NestJS in-built logger. I couldn't find an option to set the global log level. For e.g. log level as 'verbose' for dev environment and log level as 'error' for prod environment.

Also, is there an option to disable the stuff that NestJS adds in the output i.e timestamp and other info and only log the message? I need this as we use Kibana logs and it automatically adds the required fields.

Answer (score 29):

You can set up log levels in your `main.ts` file:

```ts
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
  logger: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? ['log', 'debug', 'error', 'verbose', 'warn'] : ['error', 'warn'],
});
```

Comment: 'verbose' includes all levels. `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? [ 'verbose' ] : ['error', 'warn']`

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev - I don't think this is true. I've tried it and "verbose" does not include "debug".

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev was almost correct, but 'debug' includes all levels

Comment: log levels are (in order of inclusivity): **error => warn => log => debug => verbose**.
      if you mention one level in the array then it will include all levels previous to it in the sequence above.  And if you mention multiple levels, then only those levels will be allowed. e.g. `logger: ['verbose', 'error']` will include only 'verbose' and 'error' logs. but `logger: ['verbose']` will include all levels.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own Logger with that logic and use it as a service or you can set it globally

```
export class MyLogger extends Logger {
  error(message: string, trace: string) {
    // add your tailored logic here
    super.error(message, trace);
  }
}
```

---

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule, {
  logger: new MyLogger(),
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess in the sample code you have given, i can check the env variable value (containing the global log level) and only log the message if a certain level is given in the env).

Comment: Yes, you can override default Logger to whatever you want. You can add custom logic f ex checking the env variable which determinate if the log should be logged or don't use default login system at all and put f ex just a console log there.

Answer (score -1):

I looked for a log level switcher me too, but I didn't found.

As proposed in the previous comment, you can create a custom logger and apply it globally to `ApplicationModule`.

This custom logger will be invoked either by Nest and by you in your controller/service/etc.

```
            NestJs
                    \
                      use -> CustomLogger 
                    /
Your business logic
```

In your CustomLogger call either super.logger (nestjs built-in logger) and also the [winston logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston).

Winston Logger can be set up with transporter for kibana and accept a log level.

```
const winstonLogger = new winston.Logger({
                 level: LOG_LEVEL,
                 transports: [
                    <here enable trasport for logstash/kibana>
                  }),
                ],
                ...
               });

export class CustomLogger extends Logger {

  debug(message: string) {
    super.error(message, trace);
    winstonLogger.error(message)
  }

  ... (the same for warn, error, etc)
}
```

Finally register the CustomLogger

```
 const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule, {
  logger: new CustomLogger(),
 });
```

Comment: I got your point but my Kibana pipeline is already wired up. It automatically picks up stuff from console logs so i don't need to do anything at all. I just need to remove the timestamp and other info that NestJS's default logger adds to the logged message. The Kibana setup adds it's own timestamp and other information.